# Send variables between activity and fragments

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I send a query from MainActivity to ExampleFragment?

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
    searchView.clearFocus()
    searchView.setQuery("", false)
    searchItem.collapseActionView()
    return false
}
```

ExampleFragment.kt

```
val searchedObserver = Observer<List<News>> { newList ->
    // Access the RecyclerView Adapter and load the data into it
    recyclerView.adapter = NewsAdapter(newList, this.context!!)
}

viewModel.getNewSearched(QUERY FROM MAINACT).observe(this, searchedObserver)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your main activity has an instance of your fragment you can pass it in through any public method:

Main Act:

```
exampleFragment.setQuery(query)
```

Frag:

```
fun setQuery(query: String) {
  // do a thing
}
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qkiwts why this happening? This should be so easy and im having so many difficults ...

Comment: @RodeigoLopes, the way you defined your `val SearchedText` is inside the scope of the function, which means the variable doesn't exist outside that function. To use it as you are trying to, you need to define it as a class variable by defining it outside the function, and only update the value inside the function.

Comment: Also you should avoid making variable names that start with a capital letter. That is considered bad practice and will make your code harder to read, always start variable names with a lowercase and class names with capitals

Comment: Can you come to TeamSpeak or Discord?

Comment: No, but i can make a chat on stackoverflow

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205551/passing-variable-in-kotlin

Comment: try now, i gave you rep

Comment: odd, when you go to make a comment does it give you the "automatically move discussion to chat" option?

Comment: Yes, but inside the chat doesnt now let me write!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a viewmodel attached in the activity's context that both the fragment and activity read and write to.

In activity:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(YOURVIEWMODEL::class.java)
```

In fragment:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this.getActivity()).get(YOURVIEWMODEL::class.java)
```

Then you can add a public variable to the viewmodel for the query variable.

Comment: There's no reason to spin up a vm as an intermediary between those. A fragment belongs to the activity so the parent can directly give to the child.

Answer (score 0):

You can add search view in your activity and override onCreateOptionsMenu() inorder to get the query inside the frgament.